# Deleting Objects in JavaScript. I'm a bit confused with JavaScript's delete operator.I have a problem with removeName (person)

Tags: javascript, object

I'm a bit confused with JavaScript's delete operator.I am begginer in JS. Take the following piece of code:

```js
let user = {
  name : "name",
  surname: "surname"
};

function removeName (person){
   delete person.name;
}

removeName(user);
console.log(user);
```

After this piece of code has been executed,I take as output
{ surname: 'surname' } but i take also a warning " Unused parameter person ". To fix it I write `this.person = person;` but it turns out to be an error `TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'person').`

Comment: If `user` variable and `function` it's in same page you can use directly `delete user.name;` else you can `return newObject` from function.

Comment: I don't get any such warning.

Comment: You haven't provided the code that's producing the issue as described.

Comment: Who/what gives you this warning? The code shown here does not appear to reproduce it. Is this from some "code quality checker" or something like that? Those tools aren't always right. (Resp. sometimes they _warn_ about things, that are not actually an _issue_ in the specific situation. Sometimes as a developer you just need to answer their "did you really intend to do this?" with a Yes, I actually did.)

Comment: You do not get the warning because I did not add this.person to the code but I describe it below.

Comment: So please @mixalispetros can you [edit] your question to make the snippet reproduce your issue ? In your case the snippet works well !

Answer (score 0):

***this*** is a keyword in javascript which refers to the object that it belongs to. Unless you have a function or object you are using the ***this*** keyword in, the value of '**this**' is undefined. Hence, when you try 'this.person', you get the error 'cannot set property of undefined'.

As for the unused parameter warnings, its highly likely that a linter is causing that. If you're using JetBrains IDE, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50266906/17489427